# Distribuindo pontos uniformemente em um círculo

Tags: matemática, random, matlab

Comecei a fazer um código para distribuir aleatoriamente pontos uniformemente em um círculo, porém, ao gerar um ponto localizado com um ângulo teta aleatório entre 0 e 2π e com uma distância do centro do círculo aleatória de 0 ao raio R, os pontos ficam amontoados mais próximos do centro.

Fiz com o seguinte código:

```
Pontos = R * rand(1,N) .* exp(j * 2 * pi * rand(1,N));
```

onde rand(1,N) é um vetor que se relaciona a N valores aleatórios de 0 a 1.
No momento em que eu tiro a raiz quadrada da primeira operação rand(1,N), ao plotar os gráficos, os pontos ficam uniformemente distribuídos:

```
Pontos = R * sqrt(rand(1,N)) .* exp(j * 2 * pi * rand(1,N));
```

Como isso pode ser explicado?

Comment: Seu problema me parece mais matemático que qualquer outra coisa.
Eu colocaria as tags *matemática* e *random* e colocaria uma imagem do seu gráfico com as duas distribuicões. Numa olhada nos resultados, eu percebo a diferenca e vejo a razão, afinal `sqrt(0.2)~0.45`, mas não consegui lembrar de um método eficiente de qualificar *randomness*.

Comment: Gente, a edição que eu fiz não foi correção do texto, foi apenas a adição que o Guto sugeriu, das tags, não entendi porque alguém colocou em correção o texto como se eu tivesse modificado e dificultado o entendimento se tá como tava antes, kkkkk

Comment: Eu consgui perceber porque que no primeiro caso os pontos ficam mais concentrados no centro. Não sei entretanto explicar o porquê de ao tirar a raíz quadrada eles se espalharem melhor, mas eu acho que eles continuam não uniforme

Comment: Não percebi o porquê você multiplica pelo exponencial de um número no fator de `j`, assim como não vi você colocando o valor do ângulo teta;.

Comment: Eu sei que faz tempo já a pergunta mas como fazia tempo que eu não abria o SOF, resolvi explicar. Uma forma de escrever um ângulo é utilizando uma exponencial com expoente i2πX, sendo i o valor do conjunto dos imaginários tal que sqrt(i)=-1. No fim, basta a gente tirar o módulo do eixo imaginário e calculamos a tangente que temos magicamente um ângulo, é bem mais simples do que parece, e j é como o matlab representa o valor imaginário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme apontado anteriormente, de fato sua questão é de matemática.

### A origem do problema

O problema é que você está tomando uma distribuição uniforme de raios, i.e., a probabilidade de um ponto estar a uma distância qualquer *r* do centro não depende de *r*. A maneira intuitiva de ver que isso não produz uma distribuição uniforme na área do círculo é a seguinte: se a probabilidade de um ponto estar a uma distância *r* do centro é a mesma pra qualquer *r*, você espera encontrar em média o mesmo número de pontos a uma distância *r* do centro, para todo *r*.

Ademais, como a probabilidade independe do ângulo, os pontos a uma distância *r* devem se distribuir igualmente sobre uma circunferência de raio *r*. Acontece que para *r* grande as circunferências vão ficando maiores, e como você está distribuindo o mesmo número de pontos sobre elas, é de se esperar que os pontos fiquem mais espaçados uns dos outros!

Para que a distribuição fique uniforme em termos de área, você precisa colocar mais pontos sobre as circunferências maiores, ou em outras palavras, a probabilidade de se colocar um certo ponto a uma distância *r* deve crescer com *r*. Mas crescer como? Uma vez que o tamanho das circunferências cresce linearmente com o raio (=2π*r*), é de se esperar que essa probabilidade cresça também linearmente com *r*. Para ver isso de forma mais rigorosa precisamos de mais matemática.

### Distribuição de raios

Ocorre que os elementos de área em coordenadas esféricas dependem do raio, ficando maiores para *r* maiores:

```
dA = r dr dθ,
```

e para que a distribuição seja de fato uniforme, você quer que a probabilidade de haver um ponto em um dado elemento de área seja constante para qualquer elemento. Essa probabilidade é, pela definição de densidade de probabilidade, *P(r,θ) dA*, ou seja, *P(r,θ) r dr dθ*.

Integrando isso para *r* entre 0 e *R* e *θ* entre 0 e 2π você tem a probabilidade total do ponto cair em algum lugar no círculo, que deve ser 1. Não é difícil ver que isso fixa

```
P(r,θ) = 1 / (πR²),
```

o que é óbvio: numa distribuição homogênea sobre uma determinada área total, a probabilidade associada a um elemento de área deve ser a razão entre a área do elemento e a área total. Veja que é exatamente isso que dá o produto *P(r,θ) dA*:

```
P(r,θ) dA = r dr dθ / (πR²).
```

#### Variável inomogênea

Pois bem, então agora você pode interpretar esse resultado de forma um pouco diferente. Em vez das variáveis *r* e *θ*, mudamos para duas variáveis aleatórias *x* (que varia entre 0 e *R*) e *y* (que varia entre 0 e 2π) que possuem agora uma densidade de probabilidade

```
P(x,y) = x / (πR²)
```

de modo que a integral disso pra *x* indo de 0 a *R* e *y* indo de 0 a 2π seja 1:

```
∫∫ P(x,y) dx dy = 1.
```

Veja que agora sua densidade de probabilidade *P(x,y)* de fato não depende de *y* mas é proporcional a *x*! Esse é o resultado que menciono no início: na verdade você está procurando uma variável aleatória *x* entre 0 e *R* mas cuja distribuição não é uniforme, sendo na verdade proporcional a *x*.

Para entender a raiz quadrada em rand(1,N) ainda precisamos avançar um pouco mais.

Uma pequena tecnicalidade: as variáveis *x* e *y* são independentes, pois podemos reescrever *P(x,y)* como um produto

```
P(x,y) = f(x)g(y).
```

É fácil ver que a escolha adequada é

```
g(y) = 1/2π
```

de modo que ∫g(y) dy = 1 para a integral entre 0 e 2π, e

```
f(x) = 2x/R²
```

tal que ∫f(x) dx = 1 para *x* entre 0 e *R*. Observe que *f(x)g(y)* de fato recupera *P(x,y)*.

Como *g(y)* não depende de *y*, vemos que o ângulo é realmente distribuído homogeneamente (o que explica porque você pode usar 2*pi*rand(1,N) dentro da exponencial).

O desafio então agora é buscar uma variável *x* distribuída de acordo com a densidade de probabilidade *f(x)* acima.

#### Método da transformação

Um método para se fazer isso a partir de variáveis distribuídas uniformemente é o chamado *método da transformação*.

Para variáveis *x* distribuídas de 0 a *R* de acordo com uma distribuição *f(x)*, a fração de números que caem entre 0 e *x*, que chamaremos de *F(x)*, é dada por

```
F(x) = ∫f(x') dx',
```

com a integral realizada entre 0 e *x*.

Acontece que para números uniformemente distribuídos entre 0 e 1, a fração de números que caem entre 0 e *G* (para um dado *G* entre 0 e 1) é exatamente *G*. Veja: a fração de números entre 0 e 1/2 é 1/2, entre 0 e 1/3 é 1/3, e por aí vai.

Então a fração de números entre 0 e um dado *F(x)* para números distribuídos homogeneamente entre 0 e 1 é *F(x)*, que é exatamente a fração de números entre 0 e x na distribuição *f(x)* definida entre 0 e *R*.

O que queremos portanto é mapear o intervalo entre 0 e *F(x)* de números *r* distribuídos homogeneamente no intervalo de 0 a x da nova distribuição. E isso é bem fácil de fazer: os extremos dos intervalos devem corresponder! Assim o número *x* da distribuição não-uniforme deve ser obtido quando o número

```
r = F(x)
```

for obtido na distribuição uniforme. Conclusão: dados os números *r* distribuídos uniformemente, basta inverter essa relação - encontrando a função inversa de *F(x)* - para obter o *x*. Vamos aplicar essa ideia à nossa f(x) acima.

Temos f(x) = 2x/R², de modo que, lembrando que a integral é realizada entre 0 e *x*,

```
F(x) = ∫f(x') dx' = ∫2x'/R² dx' = x²/R².
```

Inverter essa relação é fácil:

```
r = F(x) => r = x²/R² => x = R √r
```

o que (finalmente!) mostra que uma variável x distribuída entre 0 e *R* com densidade de probabilidade *f(x)* = *2x/R²* pode ser obtida simplesmente multiplicando-se *R* pela raiz quadrada de uma variável *r* homogeneamente distribuída entre 0 e 1. Isso é exatamente o que você está fazendo com

```
R * sqrt(rand(1,N))
```

na sua segunda linha de código. Essa sua solução 'empírica' portanto realmente fornece exatamente números homogeneamente distribuídos sobre um círculo de raio *R*.